# Mimicking Lightning Record Page in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

So I'm working on something and I'm just sort of stuck scratching my head.  I'm utilizing tabs to try to create a segmented version of a page layout.  We have just way too many fields and they are all necessary.  So I thought to do horizontal tabs, like lightning allows but not for records.  (The tabs in lightning allow a full layout to be rendered, not to split up layout like I want to)

Anyway, my code works and saves and inline edits.  However, I cannot for the life of my figure out how to align it like a regular page renders.

[image: alignment example]

Top is VF and bottom is the page layout on Record Page.  The goal is I want my visualforce to mimic the spacing and feel of layout but with my ability to utilize tabs.

Basically it looks like a mixture of right aligning and just empty space.

If I remove my page block sections/items I can get it to align on left, but it won't function as 2 columns.  I've tried rendering a table, it works but the table stretches when you inline edit and it looks odd.

```
  <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" lightningStylesheets="true"> 
    <apex:form >
   <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="theTabPanel">
   
        <apex:tab label="Opportunity Information" name="name1" id="tabOne">
      <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton" />
                <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
         <apex:pageMessages />
         <!-- Display Save and Cancel Button -->

         <!-- A PageBlockSection for Entry and Display opportunity Values --> 
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="look for me">
            
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity Name"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.Name}">
                <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" 
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            a
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity Type"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.Type}">
                <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                   
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
             
          
        </apex:pageBlock> 
             </apex:tab>  
            

    <apex:tab label="Inside Sales Section" name="name2" id="tabTwo">
          <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton" />
        <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        
        
             <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!opportunity.ACV__c}">
                    </apex:outputText>
                
                    <apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.NextStep}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>                       
                    </apex:outputField>
                  
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         
      
          
        </apex:pageBlock> 
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
   </apex:form>
   
   </apex:page>
```

Comment: I would have thought you would be better off dropping as much standard VF apex: element use to replace it with HTML using the SLDS blueprints. There will be a lot you would have to do yourself, of course, using JavaScript and probably VFRemoting if you want to reduce the page rendering burden.

Comment: This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Have you considered just writing a Lightning Component to display the fields you want? I'd recommend a reusable component that accepts the name of a Field Set to display the fields you want to display, or maybe some sort of configuration file as a static resource if you want more control (e.g. 1-2 column support, sections, etc).

Comment: It is true that you could then drop the component sfdcfox suggests into a VF page and thus have it accessible in Classic UI.

Comment: Would the component then allow me to do inline editing?  Or would I need to custom build that?  The VF has it innately which is why I thought it to be an easier solution.  I figured there was just some sort of way to style the pageblock to mimic.